# span inside of lightbox won't trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have added a CodePen Demo

I'm trying to make the lightbox close when the close button is clicked. Currently, the lightbox will only "close" or trigger the close function on the background only.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/GizmoJ/pen/rYOyNL)

So far I have tried these slectors that don't trigger the closing function:

```
$('.lightbox-item > .close-button')
$('.lightbox-item .close-button')
$('.close-button')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the click event on the document using `$(document).on('click', '.lightbox-item .close-button', function(){ closeLightbox(); });` because the `div` lightbox-item is empty when you run `$('.lightbot-item .close-button').click(function(){ closeLightbox(); });` at the end of your code.

You can also bind the click event after you append the content in the function `openLightbox`. It would look like this

```
$(".lightbox-item").append(content);
$('.lightbox-item .close-button').click(function(){ closeLightbox(); });
```

I created a fork of your [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXQdYr?editors=1010) using the first solution.

Comment: This worked! Although I do prefer binding the click event after appending the content.